# Compiler help (transition matrix)

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

i have a matrix with all the transitions in my programming language. 
lets say i have the following code:

> ```
> if(x=0)
> {
> x=10;
> }
> ```

when  i start reading '(' i store the word "if", but then after i do that i loss the character '(' . How can i do to keep the parenthesis??
so far my code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <Code.Length ; i++)
{
char CurrentChar= code[i];
for (int j = 0; j < Chars.Length; j++)
{ 
if (CurrentChar == '(')
{ 
column= 15;
i--; 
} 
}
```

but then it loops and stays on reading the '(' and wont continue reading the rest of the code.

Comment: It's very unclear what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: what i need to do is to create my tokens table, so i just typed the part of the parenthesis..

Comment: @CarlosApple if you show us how you store `if` maybe we can tell you how to store `(` also.

Comment: no, if CurrentChar == '('  then i want to save it with its token value. What i meant is that when i read the word if my "i" value is 2, (which is the value of the position of '(', then i store the word if, but when i look again i loss the parenthesis because then i's value will be 3.. (which corresponds to letter x)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is looping is because you are moving i back to before the '(' and then the for loop is moving you back up to the '('. This will loop infinitely.

Example:

- When i = 2:

  - CurrentChar == '('

    - column = 15
    - i = i-1 so i becomes 1
- Loop iteration finishes

  - i = i + 1 so i becomes 2;
- When i = 2:...

Your code description above does not make it possible for me to provide a solution to your dilemma however. I can only tell you what is causing the infinite loop.

**EDIT:** The best I can provide is what I know in general about token collecting. You will need a buffer for your current token that is saved off when you reach a delimiter. Here is a rough example (again, without better clarification I can do very little to help):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(){
        var code = @"if(x=0)
{
x=10;
}";
        var tokens = new List<string>();
        var token = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            char CurrentChar = code[i];
            if(CurrentChar == '(')
            {
                tokens.Add(token.ToString());
                token = new StringBuilder();
            }
            // Do checks for other tokens
            else
            {
                token.Append(code[i]);
            }
        }
        foreach(var tkn in tokens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tkn);
        }
    }
}
```